# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "G"

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;

public class ResponseTimeProject
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
         Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
         Random rand = new Random();

         System.out.print("Please enter your full name: ");
         String name = in.nextLine();

         System.out.println ("Hello " + name 
         + ". Please answer as fast as you can."
         + "\n\nHit <ENTER> when ready for the question.");
         in.nextLine();

         String alphabet="ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
         int character=(int)(Math.random()*26);
         String s=alphabet.substring(character, character+1);

         Random r = new Random();

         for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++) 
         {
             System.out.println (alphabet.charAt(r.nextInt(alphabet.length())));
         } 

         long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

         System.out.print("What is the next letter in the alphabet?" + " ");
         String response = in.nextLine();
         int letter = Integer.parseInt(response);

         long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

         String outcome;
         if  (letter == character+1)
             outcome = "Correct!";
         else
             outcome = "Incorrect.";

         long reactionTime = endTime - startTime;

         System.out.println("That took " + reactionTime + " milliseconds");
         System.out.println("Thank you "  + name + ", goodbye.");
    }
}
```

This is my code. I am trying to ask the user what the next letter in the alphabet is. I cannot figure out the correct string outcome. I want the program to tell whether or not the answer was correct.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting the `NumberFormatException` because you are trying to parse a String with alphabets into integer by doing the following:

```
int letter = Integer.parseInt(response);
```

If you want to convert it to an integer then you should be doing something like this:

```
int letter = Character.getNumericValue(response.charAt(0));
```

Answer (score 0):

It is obvious you will get NumberFormatException if you covert String "G" to integer. 
You should be checking 
`letter.equals(alphabet.substring(character+1, character+2))` rather than `letter == character+1`

here is the corrected for you

```
System.out.print("What is the next letter in the alphabet?" + " ");
String response = in.nextLine();

long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

String outcome;
if (alphabet.substring(character+1, character + 2).equals(response)) {
    outcome = "Correct!";
} else {
    outcome = "Incorrect.";
}
```